# What sets the SHELL environment variable?

Tags: terminal, bash

I've set my default shell to be the Brew-installed Bash, and that's what I get when I run Terminal.app.

[image: Terminal.app settings]

However, something is still setting `SHELL` to `/bin/zsh`, which causes problems since some programs check this variable when spawning subshells.

```
$ which bash
/usr/local/bin/bash

$ echo $BASH_VERSION
5.2.15(1)-release

$ echo $SHELL
/bin/zsh
```

What is setting this value for `SHELL`, and how do I permanently change or unset it?

Comment: Can you expand on how you changed your default shell and what dot files (`.bash_profile`, `.zshrc`, etc.) you've got configured?  This is normally set by the shell itself unless overridden.

Comment: Also, what does `echo $0` return?

Comment: @Allan - I've added a screenshot showing where I set the shell. I do have both a `.bash_profile` and `.zshrc`. Is there something in particular I should look for in those files?

Comment: @nohillside - `echo $0` returns `-bash`. I wonder what that means.

Comment: It means you are running `bash` as a login shell, so the value of `SHELL` is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The screenshot you posted doesn’t set your default shell, it runs a command when you open the default shell (which is Zsh).  In this case, you’re opening Bash *from* Zsh.

#### How to fix:

1. Reset the setting back to "Default Login Shell"
2. Issue the following command to change your login shell:

   ```
   chsh -s /usr/local/bin/bash
   ```
3. Close your Terminal windows and reopen.

Comment: That makes sense. I had to append my username to the end of that `chsh` command, but that seems to be the problem. So `chsh` is the correct way to set your default shell.

Comment: @NickChammas Yes chsh is the correct way but what do you mean by "I had to append my username to the end of that chsh command, " What exactly did you enter as Allan's line is the correct one.

Comment: @mmmmmm - I couldn't run the command Allan provided as-is. I needed `sudo` to make the shell change. But I didn't want to change the default for the root user, so I had to prepend `sudo` to the start of the command and append my username to the end of the command. i.e. `sudo chsh -s /usr/... nchammas`